# Django ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /u/1/

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm having the following issue, but I suspect that it is a configuration issue. The DJANGO app I'm using is open source (from GitHub). The serving components are DJANGO, NGINX and GUNICORN.

Clicking on a `user-profile` page of the site produces the following web page error (all other site links appear fine -- no issues):

```
Internal Error!
Sorry about that.
A detailed error report has been generated and has been sent to the managers.
If the problem persists please contact the site owners.
```

Underneath the covers, it looks like an error email is also constructed with the following subject:

```
[Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /u/1/
```

Again, I haven't run into any other site link that produce this issue (but I am just starting with this).

Looking at the logs, here is more information (where I substituted in `example.com` and `93.184.216.34` for the actual host/domain name and IP address), Both the host/domain name and it's IP address are specified in NGINX as well as in ALLOWED_HOSTS (live.deploy settings file). gunicorn uses a UNIX DOMAIN SOCKET to communicate with NGINX.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: [Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /u/1/
From: noreply@lvh.me
To: admin@lvh.me
Date: Tue, 26 Sep 2017 17:03:10 -0000
Message-ID: <20170926170310.692.19616@example.com>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 137, in get_response
    response = response.render()

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 80, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 56, in resolve_template
    return loader.select_template(template)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 180, in select_template
    return get_template(template_name)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 127, in find_template
    source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 43, in __call__
    return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 49, in load_template
    template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 149, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 125, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 153, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 278, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 215, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 278, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 190, in do_block
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock',))

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 278, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 942, in do_if
    nodelist = parser.parse(('elif', 'else', 'endif'))

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 276, in parse
    self.invalid_block_tag(token, command, parse_until)

  File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/biostar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 331, in invalid_block_tag
    (command, get_text_list(["'%s'" % p for p in parse_until])))

TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'endblock', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'


<WSGIRequest
path:/u/1/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'biostar2': '8fatnvziwin0wg1mf4ufeoxkg7c6bkt1',
 'csrftoken': 'Zk99UboOd7VXjCUzRhuvOwRJrywQRbNr'},
META:{u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'Zk99UboOd7VXjCUzRhuvOwRJrywQRbNr',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=Zk99UboOd7VXjCUzRhuvOwRJrywQRbNr; biostar2=8fatnvziwin0wg1mf4ufeoxkg7c6bkt1',
 'HTTP_DNT': '1',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'example.com',
 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://example.com/user/list/',
 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.29 Safari/537.36',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '93.184.216.34',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/u/1/',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'RAW_URI': '/u/1/',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'example.com',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/19.7.1',
 'gunicorn.socket': <socket._socketobject object at 0x7f4a14d12600>,
 'wsgi.errors': <gunicorn.http.wsgi.WSGIErrorsWrapper object at 0x7f4a159bac90>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class 'gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper'>,
 'wsgi.input': <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x7f4a14cfce10>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream biostar_server {
    server unix:/home/www/sites/biostar-central/live/rootfs/var/run/biostar.gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

# When no server names match then crash out.
server {
   return 404;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 5M;
    server_name 93.184.216.34 example.com;

    keepalive_timeout 25s;

    # Path for static files.
    root /home/www/sites/biostar-central/live/export/;
    access_log /home/www/sites/biostar-central/live/rootfs/var/log/biostar.nginx.access.log;
    error_log  /home/www/sites/biostar-central/live/rootfs/var/log/biostar.nginx.error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        alias    /home/www/sites/biostar-central/live/export/static/favicon.ico;
    }

    location = /sitemap.xml {
        alias    /home/www/sites/biostar-central/live/export/static/sitemap.xml;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        alias    /home/www/sites/biostar-central/live/export/static/robots.txt;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://biostar_server;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}

# Redirect domains.
# Commented out to simplify troubleshooting.
#server {
#    listen 80;

    # Redirect to www.
    #server_name example.com;
    #rewrite ^(.*) http://www.example.com$1 permanent;

    # Redirect to non-www.
    #server_name www.example.com;
    #return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
#}
```

Any ideas?
I tried a ton of things, but apparently not the correct thing. =:)

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**:
Note that the [GitHub software](https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central) is quite stable and running a few sites for a long while now, so if the issue is **template syntax** related, I would've expected a correction to be checked into GitHub by now (because the developer is pretty good and on top of things with the code and sites). But pretending that a correction hasn't been checked back into GitHub, then adopters of it would have had to fix any syntax errors at implementation time. Unfortunately I'm not a DJANGO developer, so assuming it is a template syntax issue, any pointers on how to track the errant file and syntax is appreciated. But again, this is stable software. Thanks!

**EDIT-2:**
Here is a pastebin URL of the problematic URL when DEBUG=True was set (and the URL was revisited): https://pastebin.com/EG1UTdmA

Comment: Its a simple template syntax error originating from template nothing to do with nginx or gunicorn. You are probably missing the closing tag for one of template tag, please show the template which `user-profile` renders.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and help. :) See my EDIT above. It is available at the GitHub link above.

Comment: Yup the `/u/1/` url works locally, have you tried to override the template `biostar/server/templates/user_details.html` in any way?

Comment: No, I haven't. I wouldn't know how. :) The only overrides are to the default Django settings shipped, and those are few (like ALLOW_HOSTS, EMAIL_HOST, ... basic things like that; nothing fancy).

Comment: Try to enable the `DEBUG` mode e.g. `DEBUG=True` in settings, and then visit the problematic URL again and capture the more descriptive error. Or if possible could you share the URL of the site where you are running it? (after enabling the DEBUG mode).

Comment: Good idea @AamirAdnan I enabled DEBUG=True and captured the HTML result after visiting the problematic URL. Let me push it through a regex to remove sensitive information and I'll post it somewhere and let you know. Meanwhile I also have a GitHub issue open, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155364/discussion-between-prismalytics-io-and-aamir-adnan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the open source software that I was using (caused by an errant GitHub merge). The developer quickly fixed the issue and posted the update on GitHub.

Of note, however, I want to thank @aamir-adnan (commenter above) who jumped right in and dug through this question, trying to find the culprit. Part of that effort isn't seen above because it occurred via a StackOverflow chat session. So, thank you Aamir!